# Itunes Connect error upload binary

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect, cordova-plugins

I'm having serious problems when trying to upload my binary to iTunes Connect portal. Call the Apple support but did not receive a solution as I was told that from there is all good and no problems.

Every time I get a binary so the minute appears in iTunes Connect

[image]

The only message that appears on the error is: There was an error importing this compilation.

Then you receive an email from Apple that my application has problems with "aps-environment" for Push Notifications. I realized I had no set of all notifications so create the certificate notifications, also the production profile, configure my application from XCODE and apparently did everything right as from the same media was told that indeed those filesThey are created and loaded in my app.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can not find information about this error, less support. Neither I worked communicating with Apple support. I'm working this application with Ionic Framework. If someone could help me, this is the first time I get an application for IOS with Push Notification. Any other information needed can be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I uploaded with xCode, but works fine with "Application Loader".

1. I exported the binary in xCode.
2. I selected "Save for iOS AppStore Deployment".
3. Then I uploaded the binary from "Application Loader" and work fine.